# Apache oozie spark workflow keeps running for a long time before getting killed when run in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I am trying to run an OOZIE workflow using spark-action using yarn-cluster as master. The app seems to run fine when I use spark-submit from command line like this:

```
./bin/spark-submit --verbose --class com.demo.spark.hdfs.SparkHDFSDemo --master yarn-cluster hdfs://namenode:8020/user/root/word-count/spark-hdfs.jar
```

But when I try to run same application using spark-action it keeps running for about 20 minutes and then gets killed. Following is my job.properties:

```
nameNode=hdfs://namenode:8020
jobTracker=job-tracker:8050
master=yarn-cluster
name=spark-hdfs-word-count
class=com.demo.spark.hdfs.SparkHDFSDemo
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/root/word-count/spark-hdfs-workflow.xml
jar=${nameNode}/user/root/word-count/spark-hdfs.jar
```

And below is my spark-hdfs-workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="word-count-001" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    <start to="spark-hdfs" />
    <action name="spark-hdfs">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <name>${name}</name>
            <class>${class}</class>
            <jar>${jar}</jar>
         </spark>
        <ok to="end" />
      <error to="kill" />
   </action>
   <kill name="kill">
      <message>failed</message>
   </kill>
   <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

I have also checked my HDFS share lib contents and they do have spark-assembly.jar along with other jars. Below are the logs that are taken from YARN resource manager UI:

```
2015-08-30 05:09:57,616 INFO [ContainerLauncher #0] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : namenode:45454
2015-08-30 05:09:57,664 INFO [ContainerLauncher #0] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: Shuffle port returned by ContainerManager for attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 : 13562
2015-08-30 05:09:57,665 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: TaskAttempt: [attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0] using containerId: [container_e06_1440917812423_0018_01_000002 on NM: [namenode:45454]
2015-08-30 05:09:57,667 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from ASSIGNED to RUNNING
2015-08-30 05:09:57,667 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: task_1440917812423_0018_m_000000 Task Transitioned from SCHEDULED to RUNNING
2015-08-30 05:09:58,264 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: getResources() for application_1440917812423_0018: ask=1 release= 0 newContainers=0 finishedContainers=0 resourcelimit=<memory:70656, vCores:1> knownNMs=6
2015-08-30 05:09:58,993 INFO [Socket Reader #1 for port 60060] SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for job_1440917812423_0018 (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-08-30 05:09:59,014 INFO [IPC Server handler 0 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: JVM with ID : jvm_1440917812423_0018_m_6597069766658 asked for a task
2015-08-30 05:09:59,014 INFO [IPC Server handler 0 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: JVM with ID: jvm_1440917812423_0018_m_6597069766658 given task: attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0
2015-08-30 05:10:05,741 INFO [IPC Server handler 1 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:10:35,789 INFO [IPC Server handler 15 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:11:05,829 INFO [IPC Server handler 22 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:11:35,868 INFO [IPC Server handler 14 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:12:05,898 INFO [IPC Server handler 13 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:12:35,932 INFO [IPC Server handler 8 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:13:05,979 INFO [IPC Server handler 18 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:13:36,010 INFO [IPC Server handler 27 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:14:03,046 INFO [IPC Server handler 16 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:14:33,073 INFO [IPC Server handler 10 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:15:03,117 INFO [IPC Server handler 18 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:15:33,160 INFO [IPC Server handler 6 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:16:03,227 INFO [IPC Server handler 23 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:16:33,254 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:17:03,292 INFO [IPC Server handler 22 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:17:33,328 INFO [IPC Server handler 1 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:18:03,374 INFO [IPC Server handler 6 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:18:33,445 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:19:03,478 INFO [IPC Server handler 12 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:19:33,513 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:20:03,568 INFO [IPC Server handler 26 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:20:33,592 INFO [IPC Server handler 1 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:21:03,624 INFO [IPC Server handler 23 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:21:33,652 INFO [IPC Server handler 11 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:22:03,680 INFO [IPC Server handler 22 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:22:33,705 INFO [IPC Server handler 18 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:23:03,735 INFO [IPC Server handler 13 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:23:33,761 INFO [IPC Server handler 16 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:24:03,801 INFO [IPC Server handler 11 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:24:33,822 INFO [IPC Server handler 8 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:25:03,846 INFO [IPC Server handler 22 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:25:33,873 INFO [IPC Server handler 2 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:26:03,909 INFO [IPC Server handler 20 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:26:33,931 INFO [IPC Server handler 11 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:27:03,964 INFO [IPC Server handler 16 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:27:33,999 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:28:04,029 INFO [IPC Server handler 8 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:28:34,048 INFO [IPC Server handler 20 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:29:04,072 INFO [IPC Server handler 4 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:29:34,097 INFO [IPC Server handler 29 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:30:04,131 INFO [IPC Server handler 6 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,010 INFO [IPC Server handler 17 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,027 INFO [IPC Server handler 25 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Commit-pending state update from attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,028 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from RUNNING to COMMIT_PENDING
2015-08-30 05:30:11,028 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 given a go for committing the task output.
2015-08-30 05:30:11,029 INFO [IPC Server handler 14 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Commit go/no-go request from attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,029 INFO [IPC Server handler 14 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: Result of canCommit for attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0:true
2015-08-30 05:30:11,050 INFO [IPC Server handler 15 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 is : 1.0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,052 INFO [IPC Server handler 26 on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Done acknowledgement from attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,053 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from COMMIT_PENDING to SUCCESS_CONTAINER_CLEANUP
2015-08-30 05:30:11,054 INFO [ContainerLauncher #1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: Processing the event EventType: CONTAINER_REMOTE_CLEANUP for container container_e06_1440917812423_0018_01_000002 taskAttempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,054 INFO [ContainerLauncher #1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl: KILLING attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,055 INFO [ContainerLauncher #1] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : namenode:45454
2015-08-30 05:30:11,071 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0 TaskAttempt Transitioned from SUCCESS_CONTAINER_CLEANUP to SUCCEEDED
2015-08-30 05:30:11,080 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: Task succeeded with attempt attempt_1440917812423_0018_m_000000_0
2015-08-30 05:30:11,080 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskImpl: task_1440917812423_0018_m_000000 Task Transitioned from RUNNING to SUCCEEDED
2015-08-30 05:30:11,082 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Num completed Tasks: 1
2015-08-30 05:30:11,082 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: job_1440917812423_0018Job Transitioned from RUNNING to COMMITTING
2015-08-30 05:30:11,083 INFO [CommitterEvent Processor #1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler: Processing the event EventType: JOB_COMMIT
2015-08-30 05:30:11,115 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Calling handler for JobFinishedEvent 
2015-08-30 05:30:11,115 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: job_1440917812423_0018Job Transitioned from COMMITTING to SUCCEEDED
2015-08-30 05:30:11,116 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: We are finishing cleanly so this is the last retry
2015-08-30 05:30:11,116 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Notify RMCommunicator isAMLastRetry: true
2015-08-30 05:30:11,116 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator: RMCommunicator notified that shouldUnregistered is: true
2015-08-30 05:30:11,116 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Notify JHEH isAMLastRetry: true
2015-08-30 05:30:11,116 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: JobHistoryEventHandler notified that forceJobCompletion is true
2015-08-30 05:30:11,116 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Calling stop for all the services
2015-08-30 05:30:11,116 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Stopping JobHistoryEventHandler. Size of the outstanding queue size is 1
2015-08-30 05:30:11,119 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: In stop, writing event JOB_FINISHED
2015-08-30 05:30:11,162 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Copying hdfs://namenode:8020/user/root/.staging/job_1440917812423_0018/job_1440917812423_0018_1.jhist to hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018-1440925786804-root-oozie%3Alauncher%3AT%3Dspark%3AW%3Dword%2Dcount%2D001%3AA%3Dspark%2Dhd-1440927011114-1-0-SUCCEEDED-default-1440925795210.jhist_tmp
2015-08-30 05:30:11,187 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Copied to done location: hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018-1440925786804-root-oozie%3Alauncher%3AT%3Dspark%3AW%3Dword%2Dcount%2D001%3AA%3Dspark%2Dhd-1440927011114-1-0-SUCCEEDED-default-1440925795210.jhist_tmp
2015-08-30 05:30:11,189 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Copying hdfs://namenode:8020/user/root/.staging/job_1440917812423_0018/job_1440917812423_0018_1_conf.xml to hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018_conf.xml_tmp
2015-08-30 05:30:11,211 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Copied to done location: hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018_conf.xml_tmp
2015-08-30 05:30:11,214 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Moved tmp to done: hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018.summary_tmp to hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018.summary
2015-08-30 05:30:11,216 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Moved tmp to done: hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018_conf.xml_tmp to hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018_conf.xml
2015-08-30 05:30:11,217 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Moved tmp to done: hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018-1440925786804-root-oozie%3Alauncher%3AT%3Dspark%3AW%3Dword%2Dcount%2D001%3AA%3Dspark%2Dhd-1440927011114-1-0-SUCCEEDED-default-1440925795210.jhist_tmp to hdfs://namenode:8020/mr-history/tmp/root/job_1440917812423_0018-1440925786804-root-oozie%3Alauncher%3AT%3Dspark%3AW%3Dword%2Dcount%2D001%3AA%3Dspark%2Dhd-1440927011114-1-0-SUCCEEDED-default-1440925795210.jhist
2015-08-30 05:30:11,217 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Stopped JobHistoryEventHandler. super.stop()
2015-08-30 05:30:11,219 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator: Setting job diagnostics to 
2015-08-30 05:30:11,219 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator: History url is http://namenode:19888/jobhistory/job/job_1440917812423_0018
2015-08-30 05:30:11,224 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
2015-08-30 05:30:12,226 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Final Stats: PendingReds:0 ScheduledMaps:0 ScheduledReds:0 AssignedMaps:1 AssignedReds:0 CompletedMaps:0 CompletedReds:0 ContAlloc:1 ContRel:0 HostLocal:0 RackLocal:0
2015-08-30 05:30:12,228 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Deleting staging directory hdfs://namenode:8020 /user/root/.staging/job_1440917812423_0018
2015-08-30 05:30:12,231 INFO [Thread-105] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 60060
2015-08-30 05:30:12,246 INFO [TaskHeartbeatHandler PingChecker] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.TaskHeartbeatHandler: TaskHeartbeatHandler thread interrupted
2015-08-30 05:30:12,246 INFO [IPC Server listener on 60060] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 60060
2015-08-30 05:30:12,246 INFO [IPC Server Responder] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
```

[image: As seen in the logs it takes around 20 minutes but no error and then gets killed gracefully.]

I found these logs from job history server UI. Don't know why it is trying to connect to localhost on port 8032 as the application is running on a cluster of 6 nodes.

```
Error: application failed with exception
java.net.ConnectException: Call From ip-namenode.internal/namenode to  0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getClusterMetrics(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getClusterMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getYarnClusterMetrics(YarnClientImpl.java:506)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$submitApplication$1.apply(Client.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$submitApplication$1.apply(Client.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.logInfo(Client.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Cannot get much information from these logs as it does not show any error but the job runs and then gets killed without any error log. Totally lost for what can be the cause of this, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I've also asked a similar question in the HW community. People there have suggested changing your yarn.resourcemanager.address to use 8032 as a workaround. I've not tried this though as I'm hoping to find out what is actually happening.
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/20963/jobtracker-jobproperties-setting-not-being-respect.html